# Socket.io 1.0 | Replacements for socket.set() and socket.get()

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I would like to know how can I change bellow code from socket.io 0.9 to socket.io 1.0.

I know that socket.get(key, callback) and socket.set(key, value, callback) was deprecated.
However that, I don't know how to migrate it.

```
socket.on('check credential', function (client) {

  ...

  socket.set('client', client, function () {
    socketsOf[client.roomId][client.userName] = socket;
    if (client.userName) {
           console.log('user ' + client.userName + '@' + client.roomId + ' connected');
    }
  });
});


socket.on('request log', function (data) {
  socket.get('client', function (err, client) {
    if (err || client === undefined) {
      return;
    }
    emitToRoom(client.roomId, 'request log', {}, function (log) {
      socket.emit('update log', log);
    });
  });
});
```